# Dishwasher Drain Into Sink instead of Under?

Tags: pipe, sink, drainage, dishwasher

Is it ok to have the drain hose of the dishwasher just set into the kitchen sink and set in place, or do I have to merge it with the drain under the sink?

I am leaving this apartment soon (with my dishwasher), have a huge sink, and don't care aesthetically if there's a hose.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like a problem to me, as long as you can make sure the hose doesn't flop out of the sink and pump the DW contents all over your floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dishwasher goes to pump out then the pressure will move the hose possibly blowing it all over your kitchen.

Think of a hose left on full without anyone holding it.

You will need to clamp it down somehow and even then expect some splashing.

Good luck!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :).  A wet cloth on the drain is enough to keep it in place, so just taped it down.